# ReactJS with Material-UI: How to sort an array of Material-UI's <TableRow> alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

Currently, I render Material-UI's `<Table>'s` `<TableRow>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) with an array of `<TableRow>s` and by using `.map()`. Each `<TableRow>` has a `<TableRowColumn>` that represents a first name, like so `<TableRowColumn>Josh</TableRowColumn>`.

But, if a user presses a button, I would like to sort the `<TableRow>` array alphabetically by the `<TableRowColumn>'s` first name. So say for example out of 10 `<TableRow>s`, if the array[0] had a first name Conny and array[1] had Adrian, would like the array[1] to become array[0].

What would the right approach to this? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated it.

**EDIT**

Each row would be rendered like so with the array `rows`, that has objects with properties `firstName` and `favColor`:

```
        {
          rows.map((row) => {
            return(
              <UserRow
                firstName={row.firstName}
                favColor={row.favColor}
              />
            )
          })
        }
```

And each row is defined like so:

```
const UserRow = (props) => {
  const {firstName, favColor} = props

  return (
    <TableRow>
      <TableRowColumn>{firstName}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{favColor}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would sort the array before applying the `map` operation that will create the `TableRows`.

The react way of thinking is declarative. This means that on a visual level, you should provide the elements as they should be displayed. Hence they get sorted before they are passed to the view component.

For example (I couldn't use material-ui elements since the example didn't run in the stackoverflow setup. Just replace all elements of  `TableComponent` with their material-ui alter ego.):

```js
const data = [
  {firstname: "John", lastname: "Rover",  id:12},
  {firstname: "Bob",  lastname: "Taylor", id:24},
  {firstname: "Lucy", lastname: "Heart",  id:43}
]

// The table component is unaware of the data order operations
const TableComponent = ({tableData}) => <table><tbody>
  {tableData.map(d=> <tr key={d.id}>
      <td>{d.firstname}</td>
      <td>{d.lastname}</td>
  </tr>)}
</tbody></table>

// The parent component takes care of feeding the Table
// component with the data in the correct order.  
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { sortBy: "firstname"}
  handleChange = (event) => this.setState(
    {sortBy: event.target.value}
  );
  render () {
    const {data} = this.props; 
    const {sortBy} = this.state;
    const sortedData = data.sort((a,b) => a[sortBy]>b[sortBy]?1:-1)
    return <div>
      Sort by  
      <select value={sortBy} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="firstname">First Name</option>
        <option value="lastname">Last Name</option>
      </select>
      <h2>The table: </h2>
      <TableComponent tableData={sortedData} />
    </div>
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what `a.firstname>b.firstname?-1:1` is doing, and how would I make it applicable to various number of rows?

Comment: I have edited my answer. This is just the compare function I use to sort my array of table data. To extend this to various number of raws, you would need to use something else than a boolean to define what column you want to sort by.

Comment: I've updated my example to use a select instead of a radio button. I hope it helps.

Comment: I gave it an attempt but did not work with what I have. Please take a look at the original post. I've updated it with my code. In that case, how can I sort the array `rows` alphabetically by property `firstName` when a button is pressed, so that the rows are re-rendered with the sorted array?

Comment: The react way is to sort the array before mapping it to DOM elements. Hence why I don't suggest sorting the material Ui rows.

Comment: I understand so I will be sorting the array of objects, which each represents the TableRow. So how can I sort the objects based on a property `firstName` that each object has, using `this.state` and `this.setState`?

Comment: You get the order information either from the component's state or from the parent component. This really depend on your application. I did it in the state to make the example simple. You can see where I actually sort the array is when I do `const sortedData = data.sort(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full example of an app with a table where its rows can be sorted by clicking on the header.  Comments are inline and [the full example is available here](http://www.webpackbin.com/NklZd-zZG)

The table's state contains the rows which are sorted whenever a table column header is clicked as well as the property name of the sorted column.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui';
import { Table, TableBody, TableHeader, TableHeaderColumn, TableRow, TableRowColumn } from 'material-ui';

// properties of TableHeader component
let headerProps = {
  enableSelectAll: false,
  displaySelectAll: false,
  adjustForCheckbox: false
};

// initial set of rows, simulating data from the database
let rows = [
  {firstName: "Adrian", favColor: "gold", uniqueId: 0 },
  {firstName: "Alma", favColor: "green", uniqueId: 1 },
  {firstName: "Conny", favColor: "black", uniqueId: 2 },
  {firstName: "Jane", favColor: "blue", uniqueId: 3 }
];

// our table hader information, key is the name of the 
// property to sort by when the header is clicked 
let headers = [
  {name: "First Name", key: "firstName"},
  {name: "Favorite Color", key: "favColor"}
];


// our table component that can sort columns
class SortableTable extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {rows, sortBy: 'firstName'};
  }

  renderHeaders(){
    let header= headers.map( (h) => {
      return <SortableHeader 
                key={h.key}
                name={h.name}
                onClicked={()=>this.updateSortBy(h.key)} 
                isSortColumn={this.state.sortBy == h.key}/>
    });
    return <TableRow>{header}</TableRow>;
  }
  
  renderRows() {
    return this.state.rows.map( (row, i) => <UserRow {...row} key={row.uniqueId}/> );
  }
                               
  updateSortBy(sortBy){
      // multiple clicks on the same column reverse the sort order
      if( sortBy == this.state.sortBy ){
        this.setState( {rows: [...this.state.rows.reverse()]} );
        return;
      }
      
      let rows = [...this.state.rows];
      rows.sort( (a,b) => {
        if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy])
          return -1;
        if(a[sortBy] > b[sortBy])
          return 1;
        return 0;
      });
      
      this.setState({rows, sortBy});
    }

      
  render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader {...headerProps}>
              {this.renderHeaders()}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {this.renderRows()}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

  
  
function SortableHeader(props){
  let style = {
    cursor: "pointer"
  }
  if(props.isSortColumn){
    style.fontWeight = "bold";
    style.color = "black";
  }
  
  return (
    <TableHeaderColumn>
      <div style={style} onClick={() => props.onClicked()}>{props.name}</div>
    </TableHeaderColumn>
  );
}
  

function UserRow(props){
  return (
    <TableRow>
      <TableRowColumn>{props.firstName}</TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn>{props.favColor}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
  );
}

export default SortableTable;
```